# How can I make a call to rest api from express js?

Tags: express

I have build up `rest api` that are running on **port 8080**. I have created `express project` which is running on **port 3000**.

How can I make a call to `rest api` to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

My app.js is

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var jquery = require('jquery');
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log("User name = "+req.body.email+", password is "+req.body.password);
    var data = {
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password
        };

    jquery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType:"json",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/LT/login',                      
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(data.accessToken!='')
            {
              alert("login success");
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    console.log('Vishwas');
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

my index.ejs is

```
<html lang="en">                           
<% include header %>
<body>
<% include banner %>


  <div class="container">
    <div id="login-page" class="row">

        <div class="col m4 z-depth-6 card-panel offset-m4">

<!--          <form class="login-form" action="login.htm" method="post"> -->

            <div class="row">

              <div class="input-field col m12" >


                <p class="center login-form-text"> Login Form</p>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row margin">

              <div class="input-field col m12" >

                <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>

                <input class="validate" id="email" type="email">

                <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="center-align">Email</label>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row margin">

              <div class="input-field col m12" >

                <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>

                <input id="password" type="password">

                <label for="password">password</label>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">         

              <div class="input-field col m12 login-text">

                  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" />

                  <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

              <div class="input-field col m12">

                <button id="send" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" style="text-align:center">Login</button>

              </div>

            </div>



              <div class="input-field col m6">

                  <p class="margin right-align medium-small"><a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot password?</a></p>

              </div>         

            </div>



<!--          </form> -->

        </div>
  </div>
 <% include footer %>
  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                $('#send').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //console.log('seend_link clicked');
                    var data = {
                            email:"ashishg@dewsolutions.in",
                            password:"password"
                        };
                    $.post("http://localhost:3000/login",{email:"ashishg@dewsolutions.in",password:"password"},function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                });             
            });
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```